# Would disabling these following functions in PHP.INI affect Drupal 7?

Tags: security

If i disabled the following php functions:

disable_functions = escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd,exec,ini_alter,parse_ini_file,passthru,pcntl_exec,popen,proc_close,proc_get_status,proc_nice,proc_open,proc_terminate,show_source,shell_exec,symlink,system

would this affect drupal 7 in anyway? I am disabling them to increase security on my server. This was mentioned on securing an Invision powerboard forum.

Comment: http://drupal.org/requirements/php - for Drupal core it doesn't. Not sure about modules that call system functions...

Comment: Drupal 7 core and much of contrib has a testing built in. Did you try this configuration and then running tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that may cause odd debug issues down the track.

Some of those are required by [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush):

i.e:

- escapeshellarg
- escapeshellcmd

symlink is used in [system.tar.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.tar.inc/7)

Modules such as devel and advanced_help use parse_ini_file

Other contrib may use others, e.g print_pdf uses proc_open